# Apply constraint on specific data in a SQL table

Tags: sql-server

The constraint should be applied to only lets say 100 rows in the table which can be identified.Is trigger the only option ?

Comment: a selective constraint isn't really a constraint

Comment: Little bit more specific information will do a work

Comment: A constraint is just that, a constraint on the table, not on specific rows. But your question is so vague it is impossible to answer.

Comment: A constraint is based around *the contents of a specific row's columns*. If there is sufficient data *contained* within rows to identify whether each one is part of the 100, a constraint will work. Ideally, make it so that this is true.

Answer (score 0):

A CHECK constraint can sometimes be used instead of a trigger to offer some flexibility in which rows are constrained and how.